# Array to string conversion error in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I try to make an array,
this is my code,

```
$sosd='"tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001"';

$ardt=array($sosd);

$tken=$ardt['tokn'];
```

But cant get data in line 3

> error is Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\myebus_dms\grn_edit.php on line 3
>   Array

pls hel me to solve this problum.

Comment: Yeah. It's not an array. it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were doing over here is making an array of the following string

```
$sosd='"tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001"';
```

So when you write it as

```
$ardt=array($sosd);
```

And if you try using print_r then you'll get to know that it generates an array like as

```
Array
(
    [0] => "tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001"
)
```

and not as you were expecting over here like as

```
Array
(
    [tokn] => 123
    [grnn] => GRN/15/08/0001
)
```

So in order to achieve an array instead you can simply make an array as

```
$sosd=["tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001"]; //>PHP 5.4
$tken = $sosd['tokn'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the array correctly. 
you should declare it like this

```
$sosd=["tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001"];
```

or

```
$sosd=array("tokn"=>"123", "grnn"=>"GRN/15/08/0001");
```